# In Python, is there a build-in function to get the values (in list) between two given ones?

Tags: python, list

Is there a built-in function to get the values (in list) between two given ones?
For example, let `LIST` be a Python list defined as:

`LIST=[value_1, value_2, value_3,...,value_n]`

how to find the elements between (for example) `value_p` and `value_k`, where `p` is less than `k`, and `p, k` both belong to the interval `[0,n]`

Answer (score 1):

## Using list slicing

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr[3:6]
```

output:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

here 3 is p 
and  6 is k

Comment: Some tweaking might be necessary depending on what the OP means by "between" (should `value_p` and `value_k` be included or not?)

Comment: but, if these two values are numerous (and their indices not determined), how to apply this method?